# Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations ArrayList<Product> cartItems = myCart.getItemsList();

Tags: java, arraylist, unsafe, unchecked

I am getting the warning Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.  in the following code

```
ArrayList<Product> cartItems = myCart.getItemsList();
```

How to remove this warning.

Comment: Your `myCart.getItemsList` returns a raw not-parameterized `List`. You can suppress the warning by adding `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` just right before the assignment statement.

Comment: @fluffy thank you so much for the quick reply it worked for me but what if I do not want to suppress it. is there any other option?

Comment: Make the `getItemsList` return `ArrayList<Product>`. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does your `myCart.getItemsList()` returns `List` or `ArrayList`, and does the type have parameter `<Product>`?
2. You might consider using `List<Product> cartItems`, which should be sufficient in most cases, and make sure `myCart.getItemsList()` returns `List<Product>`.

Comment: public ArrayList<Product> getItemsList() {} solve my problem.